# Observable - Observer (java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to..)

Tags: observer-pattern, observers

The issue I face is how to segregate the Object data coming from the 3rd Party API notifyObservers of Observable.

The program is based on Observer pattern & I am able to successfully link the Observer to the 3rd party API Observable, which is triggering the Update method in the Observer.

**Code:** *notifyObservers* of *Observable*:

```
public void newData(String car,String model,CustFeedBack csFeed){
     setChanged();
     notifyObservers(new Object[]{car,model,csFeed});
 }
```

In the Observer Update method am trying to cast **arg** so that I can get each of the 3 data in the Object coming from the nofifyObservers

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object arg) {
        dataSubject = (DataSubject) arg;
        System.out.println(dataSubject.length);
        display();
 }
```

I am getting a java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to... Hope the issue I face is clear & await guidance on how I can proceed to break down the object data into 3 separate parts.

Comment: `update` is being called by your `notifyObservers` method, I guess? You're passing an array of objects to those `update` methods and are trying to cast this array into a type. I think you should cast it into an array of objects, instead. Should be something like `Object[] values = (Object[])arg`

Comment: @Alex I have tried that as well, but still get the ClassCastException (java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lpkg1.Model.DataSubject;)

Comment: What does the debugger say when you put a breakpoint on the line in question (`dataSubject = (DataSubject) arg;`)? What does `arg` contain and what's the type of it? Maybe it's something you do not expect.

Comment: @Alex In debug I do notice that arg contains the values which I expect. Unable to figure what I am messing up here..

Comment: That sounds strange. I don't know the dimensions of your project, but you can consider to "pull out" the needed values instead of passing them into the observer methods. Your observer knows the Observable (your first argument) and could call methods on it to gather the required information. It's actually not a solution for your specific problem but you would get around it.

Comment: @Alex unfortunately I cant do any changes to the 3rd party API which is providing the data from the notifyObserver. I will have to get the data using the Observer, as it does not provide any other mechanism to get the info.

Comment: @Alex I just realized that I had missed out the [] while trying the Object[] option. Anyway I am unable to mark the first message of yours as the right answer (no option to that), so I just voted on the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my comment as an answer :)

`update` is being called by your `notifyObservers` method, I guess? You're passing an array of objects to those update methods and are trying to cast this array into a type. I think you should cast it into an array of objects, instead. Should be something like `Object[] values = (Object[])arg`